# How to track rogue workgroups or domains

Tags: windows, domain, workgroup, ntlm, rogue

I have a strong feeling one of our desktop support techs is doing this, but I want to see if I can track this down before I start accusing people.  I just dont know how...

While logging into a local web app, the drop down lists a bunch of random entries.  I strongly feel its Workgroups not domains, but either way I want to find a way of tracing it.

Look at the following picture:

[image]

NTLM is detecting all these domains/workgroups.  How do I track them down?

I suspect someone is removing machines from the domain and entering in these as workgroups...

Comment: Well, I asked one of our techs and he said that he did it.  Still, I would like to know how to trace this.

Answer (score 3):

Use netserverenum to get back all the machines on the network.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370623(VS.85).aspx